# C++ Force preprocessor to evaluate a number

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am writing a C++ program and I have predefined objects Serial1, Serial2, Serial3, etc. I need to make a function to operate on only one of them depending on a numeric input known at compile time. I use the concatenation macro `#define SER(x) Serial##x` but in my main if use `SER(port).read()` and port is an int equal to 1, expression expands to `Serialport.read()` instead of `Serial1.read()`. However, `SER(1).read()` gives the required result. How can I force the preprocessor to evaluate variable `port` and use its value in the expansion?

BTW, I don't know the class name of Serial1, Serial2, etc so I cannot design a workaround using pointers or references

EDIT: After seeing some answers, I need to add some clarification. I need to be able to use this function with all Serial1, Serial2, etc. by calling it multiple times in a SINGLE RUN of my code. Sorry for not making that clear before!

Comment: The preprocessor cannot evaluate variables, even `const int` variables. Did you mean to make `port` a preprocessor macro?

Comment: All this is supposed to be part of a new class. I am not sure how that can work when I need to call the function outside the class. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of having objects called `Serial1`, `Serial2`, and so on, you could make an array and have `Serial[1]`, `Serial[2]`, and so on. Then you could use a variable as the index.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I don't know the type of the objects, hence I don't know what type my array has to be.

Comment: Why not just "#if condition, #endif" predecessor in this case? Then you can just make a normal variable/function for the rest of the code. That seems far more common unless your trying to construct some complex code generation macro that cant be done with templates

Comment: If you have C++11, you could make an array of pointers using `decltype`. Of course, that assumes that all the Serialx objects are the same type.

Comment: It seems like you might be asking for the impossible. It would help if you could construct a more complete example of what you want to do and showing how `Serial1` is defined, how `port` is defined, etc. Then we would have a better chance at suggesting a feasible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I finally managed to find the name of my class so I can use some pointers now

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two levels of macros to accomplish what you are trying.

```
#define SER2(x) Serial##x
#define SER(x) SER2(x)
```

Here's a test program that demonstrates the concept.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Port
{
   Port(std::string name) : name_(name) {}

   void write()
   {
      std::cout << name_ << std::endl;
   }

   std::string name_;
};

Port Serial1("PORT1");
Port Serial2("PORT2");

#define SER2(x) Serial##x
#define SER(x) SER2(x)

int main()
{
   SER(port).write();
}
```

---

Command to build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc -Dport=1
```

Output:

```
PORT1
```

---

Command to build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc -Dport=2
```

Output:

```
PORT2
```

**Update**

With the updated question, the only sensible approach is to use an array of objects and use the appropriate element of the array based on the run time data.

Comment: Thanks a lot R Sahu but I need to be able to use this function with all Serial1, Serial2, etc. by calling it multiple times in a SINGLE RUN of my code. Sorry for not making that clear before!

Comment: @niko: That's still possible :`SET(portA).write(); SER(portB).write().`. However, the preprocessor doesn't do math. `SER(1+1)` is `Serial1+1`

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you don't know the type doesn't really matter: `decltype(Serial1)` will give that. Do you know whether they all have the same type? Because if they don't, no single C++ function can return them directly. And if they don't even have a common base class, it's even harder.

The template mechanism is more powerful than the preprocessor, so it makes sense to draft that:

```
template<int N> struct Serial { };
template<> struct Serial<1> { static decltype(Serial1)* const ptr = &Serial1 };
template<> struct Serial<2> { static decltype(Serial2)* const ptr = &Serial3 };
template<> struct Serial<3> { static decltype(Serial3)* const ptr = &Serial3 };

// You can now use Serial<8/2-2>.ptr->
```

Of course, writing out the template specializations is boring. So let's get Boost.PP :

```
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO (1, 7) // Assuming you have ports 1 to 7
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
   template<> struct Serial<n> { \
       static decltype(BOOST_PP_CAT(Serial,n))* const ptr = &Serial##n; \
   };
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
```

Yes, that last line is a `#include` without quotes. And no, I'm not sure if this is an improvement ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot MSalters. I actually found the class so now I can use references or pointers and keep it simple.